# How to get reference to UIPopoverController when using adaptive segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uipopovercontroller, uistoryboardsegue

In my iOS 7 app, I detected if a segue was a popover via this check in `prepareForSegue`:

```
if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]])
```

But now that I am using adaptive segues, the Present as Popover segue is no longer returning true in the above check. This is because segue is no longer a `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue`, instead it is a `UIStoryboardPopoverPresentationSegue`. However, one cannot simply add the `Presentation` word because that's not defined.

**What is the appropriate way to detect when the segue is a popover from an adaptive segue**, as opposed to a full screen modal presentation?

And, **how do you get a reference to the popover for iOS 8**? The following is what I'm doing for iOS 7 but again because it's not a `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue` this will cause a crash.

```
UIPopoverController *popover = ((UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue).popoverController;
popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(380, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually was no need to get a reference to the popover for iOS 8. You can access the `popoverPresentationController` directly in the view controller that's presented. Then use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` to dismiss the view controller. You can set the popover content size directly in the view controller that's being presented via `preferredContentSize`. I found I had no need to obtain a reference in `prepareForSegue`, at least when running on iOS 8. iOS 7 is a different story.

Comment: Interestingly Apple seems to provide UIPopoverController instances in iOS8 just as they have worked in iOS7, for backward compatibility I suppose. So the same code running in iOS7 should work in iOS8 with one difference: In iOS8 the UIPopoverController is deallocated rather quickly if you don't store it as a strong reference. In iOS7 a weak reference to the UIPopoverController was sufficient, as iOS held it as long as it was displayed.

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on Joey's answer, which led me to what seems the new manner of achieving what we used to do with UIPopoverController.

This code in `prepareForSegue:Sender:`

```
        UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        UIPopoverPresentationController *ppc = destination.popoverPresentationController;
        ppc.delegate = self;
```

is a simple way to successfully set your view controller as delegate of a UIPopoverPresentationController much the same as you are probably used to doing with the old `UIPopoverController`.

And, of course, while you are at it you'll probably add:

```
[destination setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(300.00f, 300.00f)];
```

if you were in the habit of setting UIPopoverController size here as well.

Comment: Do you know if this snippet is compatible with ios 7?

Comment: My guess is no. I move off the older OS fairly quickly so I cannot confirm that easily.

Comment: Thank you. I confirmed early and does not work for 7 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most foolproof way to do it but you could check the popoverPresentationController property on your destination view controller. From there you can configure the popover anchor and such.

Check the "Configuring a Popover for Display" section of the UIPopoverPresentationController doc. (Not sure if we're allow to link to them at this point, are we?)

Note too that now we're talking about UIPopover*Presentation*Controllers, not UIPopoverControllers. It's a little confusing...

Comment: This does not work. This returns true on iPhone (modal) and iPad (popover): `if ([[segue destinationViewController] popoverPresentationController] != nil)`