# Get UIPopoverController reference in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, segue, uipopovercontroller

I have selected `Present as Popover` in Interface Builder for my StoryBoard Segue.

[image]

How can I get reference to UIPopoverController in `prepareForSegue`?

I tried like this, but it not goes inside the if statement.

```
    if segue is UIStoryboardPopoverSegue {
        let popoverSegue = segue as UIStoryboardPopoverSegue
        simpleTableViewController.popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController
    }
```

## UPDATE

If you need popovercontroller, just to dismiss it, then the way to dismiss an adaptive view controller is:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't check the type of the segue, rather you should check the segue identifier.

```
if segue.identifier == "popover" {
    let popoverSegue = segue as UIStoryboardPopoverSegue
    simpleTableViewController.popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController
}
```

Comment: it does not work, I get a crash at `segue as UIStoryboardPopoverSegue`

Comment: no message in terminal, but EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT in the swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional binary

Comment: You need to use the older popover segue, not the new adaptive segue.  It doesn't seem to be possible to get a reference to the popover controller with the adaptive segue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977676/how-to-get-reference-to-uipopovercontroller-when-using-adaptive-segue

Comment: Do you know what advantage the new adaptive segue has anyway?

Comment: The main thing is that things like pop over and master/detail work on iPhone as well as iPad

Answer (score 7):

When using the adaptive segue Present as Popover:

To get a reference to the `UIPopoverController` on iOS 7, you will need to check the `segue class` in `prepareForSegue` to see if it is a `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue`. If it is, access the popover via the `popoverController` property. Store that in the destination view controller if you need to dismiss it while in that view controller.

For iOS 8, `UIPopoverController` is no more, it's been replaced by `UIPopoverPresentationController`. You can access it directly within the view controller via `popoverPresentationController`, and you can easily dismiss the popover via `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

So when using that adaptive segue, if you run the app on iOS 7 the segue class will be `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue` while on iOS 8 it will be `UIStoryboardPopoverPresentationSegue`. You do not need to use the old deprecated popover segue, it's pretty neat the adaptive segue is automatically converted to the old API for backwards compatibility with Universal Storyboards.